# How to detect when SwiftUI View is being dragged over

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui, gesture

I would like to trigger an animation when the user drags a finger over my view.

I can do something like

```
Image(…)
  .rotationEffect(…)
  .animation(self.isAnimating ? .spring : .default)
  .gesture(
    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 5, coordinateSpace: .global)
      .onChanged { value in
        self.isAnimating = true
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
          self.isAnimating = false
        }
      }
  )
```

However that captures only a drag event that started over the image. A drag event that started elsewhere and then travels over the image is ignored.

I can also detect the drag events in the parent view and calculate which of the child views is being dragged over – and that's fine. However, how do I tell the child view to animate then? Updating their properties causes a re-render which of course cancels the animation.

Passing ui data like this through a model seems like an anti pattern.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find the answers helpful, or do you need more help?

Comment: See also [Is it possible to detect which View currently falls under the location of a DragGesture?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77796978/20386264)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I replaced the Image of your example by a Grid of small CardViews.
We will try to change the color of the cards that are "crossed" by the drag gesture.

We can use `PreferenceKey` to get all the `CardView`s bounds...

```
struct CardPreferenceData: Equatable {
    let index: Int
    let bounds: CGRect
}

struct CardPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = [CardPreferenceData]
    
    static var defaultValue: [CardPreferenceData] = []
    
    static func reduce(value: inout [CardPreferenceData], nextValue: () -> [CardPreferenceData]) {
        value.append(contentsOf: nextValue())
    }
}
```

here :

```
struct CardView: View {
    let index: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(index.description)
            .padding(10)
            .frame(width: 60)
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke())
            .background(
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.clear)
                        .preference(key: CardPreferenceKey.self,
                                    value: [CardPreferenceData(index: self.index, bounds: geometry.frame(in: .named("GameSpace")))])
                }
            )
    }
}
```

In the ContentView now we can collect all preferences (bounds and index) of these cards and store them in an array :

```
.onPreferenceChange(CardPreferenceKey.self){ value in
            cardsData = value
        }
```

We can now compare the positions (the `bounds`) of these CardViews to the position of the drag gesture.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(.fixed(60), spacing: 40), count: 3)
    @State private var selectedCardsIndices: [Int] = []
    @State private var cardsData: [CardPreferenceData] = []
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, content: {
            ForEach((1...12), id: \.self) { index in
                CardView(index: index)
                    .foregroundColor(selectedCardsIndices.contains(index) ? .red : .blue)
            }
        })
        .onPreferenceChange(CardPreferenceKey.self){ value in
            cardsData = value
        }
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged {drag in
                    if let data = cardsData.first(where: {$0.bounds.contains(drag.location)}) {
                        selectedCardsIndices.append(data.index)
                    }
                }
        )
        .coordinateSpace(name: "GameSpace")
    }
}
```

[image: Example]

EDIT : The small "lag" at the start of the video does not occur with the canvas. Only on the simulator. I have not tested on a real device.

Comment: how to give a line to link that?

Comment: God, why such seemingly easy things are so complicated  I pray every year before WWDC that Apple will do sth with that  Until then, +1 for you. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This helped me so much. Never even heard about priority keys. Super useful! At least after a few tutorials on what and how it worked. Helped me implement my own custom drag and drop!

Answer (score 0):

How about this way?

I set the drag over point at +30/-30 at both ends.

e.g. iPhone 12 width: 844, Endpoint: x: 30 and x: 814

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var offsetX: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var offsetY: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .offset(x: offsetX, y: offsetY)
                .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 5, coordinateSpace: .global)
                            .onChanged { value in
                                offsetX = value.translation.width
                                offsetY = value.translation.height
                                
                                print("x: \(value.location.x)")
                                print("y: \(value.location.y)")
                                
                                if value.location.x > UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 30 || value.location.x < 30 {
                                    print("End")
                                }
                                
                                if value.location.y > UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 30 || value.location.y < 30 {
                                    print("End")
                                }
                            }
                )
        }
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { drag in
                            print("drag: \(drag)")
                            userIsDraggingMap = true
                        }
                        .onEnded { drag in
                            userIsDraggingMap = false
                        }
                )
```