# Is it possible to detect which View currently falls under the location of a DragGesture?

Tags: swiftui

I would like to be able to detect if there are any views that fall under the location of a DragGesture.

I have tried adding DragGesture to each view (circle in this case) hoping the action would transfer across views for a continuous DragGesture motion. But that didn't work.

Surely there is a way?

[image: Screenshot]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView2: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image(.background)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 5)
                        .onChanged { value in
                        
                        print ("DG detetected at \(value.location.x) : \(value.location.y)")
                        })
                
            HStack {
                Circle()
                    .fill(.red)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                            .onChanged { value in
                            print ("DG in red")
                        })
            Circle()
                .fill(.white)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            Circle()
                .fill(.blue)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    
}

#Preview {
    ContentView2()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest saving the drag location in a state variable. Then you can use a `GeometryReader` behind each of the circles to detect whether the drag location is inside the circle.

Like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var dragLocation = CGPoint.zero
    @State private var dragInfo = " "

    private func dragDetector(for name: String) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            let frame = proxy.frame(in: .global)
            let isDragLocationInsideFrame = frame.contains(dragLocation)
            let isDragLocationInsideCircle = isDragLocationInsideFrame &&
                Circle().path(in: frame).contains(dragLocation)
            Color.clear
                .onChange(of: isDragLocationInsideCircle) { oldVal, newVal in
                    if dragLocation != .zero {
                        dragInfo = "\(newVal ? "entering" : "leaving") \(name)..."
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(white: 0.2)
            VStack(spacing: 50) {
                Text(dragInfo)
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                HStack {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(.red)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .background { dragDetector(for: "red") }
                    Circle()
                        .fill(.white)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .background { dragDetector(for: "white") }
                    Circle()
                        .fill(.blue)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .background { dragDetector(for: "blue") }
                }
            }
        }
        .gesture(
            DragGesture(coordinateSpace: .global)
                .onChanged { val in
                    dragLocation = val.location
                }
                .onEnded { val in
                    dragLocation = .zero
                    dragInfo = " "
                }
        )
    }
}
```

Note that it is important that the drag gesture and the `GeometryReader` and referring to the same coordinate space.

For versions of iOS before iOS 17, you would need to use the version of `.onChange` that only takes 1 parameter (just omit the parameter `oldVal`).

[image: Animation]

Comment: Well, I guess this is the definitive solution. I didn't know about it.

Comment: By the way, the coordinateSpace: .gloabal was already available in iOS 14

Comment: Yes, I ran your code and checked the docs too :)

Comment: @MatBuompy This concerns the init parameter to `DragGesture`. You're right, answer updated. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @BenzyNeez This was a great answer. But I don't understand everything that is going on. Have tried to find a tutorial on using background closures this way, but am unable to find anything that comes close.

Comment: @Bartender1382 When you put a background behind a `View`, it adopts the same frame size as the view it is applied to (the same goes for an overlay too). The background itself is another `View`, but in this case, `Color.clear` is used, because it doesn't actually need to be seen. This is surrounded by a `GeometryReader` (which is also a `View`). This allows the frame of the view to be found, which includes its position and size. Using the frame, it can be determined whether the shape encloses the drag location. An `onChange` handler is then used to perform an action when this state changes.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it using the DragGesture on the ZStack and embedded it all in a GeometryReader to split the screen in different portions inside the gesture.
The solution might be bit rough around the edges, of that I'm sure, but it is the closest I could get, I did my best.
Here's the code:

```
GeometryReader { proxy in
        let size = proxy.size
        ZStack {
            
            
            Color.black
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            HStack {
                Circle()
                    .fill(.red)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                
                Circle()
                    .fill(.white)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                
                Circle()
                    .fill(.blue)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            }
        } //: ZSTACK
        .frame(width: size.width)
        .gesture(
            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                .onChanged({ value in
                    let locationX = value.location.x
                    let locationY = value.location.y
                    
                    /// Check if we are in the middle
                    if locationY >= (size.height / 2) - 50 && locationY <= (size.height / 2) + 50 {
                        
                        let startRedCircle = locationX <= (size.width / 3 + 10)
                        let startWhiteCircle = locationX >= (size.width / 3 + 10) && locationX <= (2 *  size.width / 3 - 10)
                        let startBlueCircle = locationX >= (2 * size.width / 3 - 10) && locationX <= (3 *  size.width / 3 - 30)
                        
                        if (startRedCircle) {
                            print("Red")
                        } else if (startWhiteCircle) {
                            print("White")
                        } else if(startBlueCircle) {
                            print("Blue")
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                    
                    
                })
        )
        
    } //: GEOMETRY
```

Of course you may need some adjustments based on your specific needs.
And here's the result: [image: Detect circle color]

Let me know if it was of any help!